# Vee-validate: Custom rule gets multiple times called

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I have a custom rule to check if a name is unique, the textfield exists multiple times in my form, because the the form is repeatable

I have done a small simplyfied demo there -> https://codesandbox.io/s/v81mxn2ojy take a look in the console to see that the validation gets multiple times called if I write inside  the textfields. It stacks if I switch between the textfields and change the value.

template

```
<p class="sizes__input" v-for="(size, i) in sizes">
  <span>Size: </span>
  <input
    type="text"
    :name="`prefix${i}`"
    class="textfield max-dim__input"
    v-model="size.prefix"
    maxlength="8"
    autocomplete="off"
    v-validate="{ required: true, unique: prefixes }"
    :class="{ error: errors.has(`prefix${i}`) }"
  />
</p>
```

script

```
data() {
    return {
      sizes: [
        { prefix: "xl_", width: "1400", height: "1400" },
        { prefix: "l_", width: "1100", height: "1100" },
        { prefix: "m_", width: "800", height: "800" },
        { prefix: "s_", width: "600", height: "600" },
        { prefix: "thumb_", width: "200", height: "200" }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    prefixes() {
      console.log("prefix");
      if (this.sizes) {
        return this.sizes.map(item => {
          return item.prefix;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

rule

```
const unique = {
  getMessage(field) {
    return `Such ${field} already exists.`;
  },
  validate(value, args) {
    if (value) {
      console.log(value, args, args.indexOf(value));
      return args.indexOf(value) === -1;
    }
    return false;
  }
};

Validator.extend("unique", unique, {
  immediate: false
});
```

**ok found a solution** On focus I filter the data and send this to my validator.

inputfield

```
<input
    v-validate="{ required: true, unique: filteredSizes }"
    @focus="filterSizes(i);"
```

added filteredSizes

```
data() {
  return {
    filteredSizes: [],
    sizes:
```

on focus

```
filterSizes(i) {
  const otherSizes = [...this.sizes];
  otherSizes.splice(i, 1);
  this.filteredSizes = otherSizes.map(item => {
    return item.prefix;
  });
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/38qyyymyw5

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may be this.

You need use `blur` behavior. There are alternative events that might give you the same behavior of `blur` using `data-vv-validate-on` attribute to override the default events.

Examples:

For the multiselect it emits close event when the dropdown is closed which is also when the user leaves the control.

```
<multiselect data-vv-validate-on="input|close" ...>
```

For the date-picker you can instead validate on closed since that event emits when the user leaves the control.

```
<datepicker data-vv-validate-on="input|closed" ...>
```

[VeeValidate Doc](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/events.html#changing-events-per-field)

I hope this help.

Comment: sry don't understand your answer what you wanted to tell me ;) but I found a solution. But your tipp about blur helped me to get in the right direction, using focus ;)